# Able to be referenced

Tags: single-word-requests

Referenceable isn't a real word, but is there a word that means the same as "able to be referenced" that I can use?

An example of how I'd like to use it:
"The nice thing about written information, is that it's referenceable."

Thanks!

Comment: I'm willing to believe that *referenceable* is a real word. Its meaning is certainly understandable and it shows up many times on [Google](http://www.google.ca/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=referenceable) and in Google's [Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=referenceable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creferenceable%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 5):

Although "*referenceable*" may be vying for a position in the dictionary, it has three functional synonyms in place until the matter is settled:

*[Researchable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/research?q=researchable#research__25)* refers to the ability of written language to be found:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]    1 Investigate systematically:
>
> ...
>
> Derivatives
>
> researchable
>
> *The nice thing about written information, is that it's **researchable.***

[Citable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cite?q=citable#cite__17) refers to the ability of written language to be shared:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]   1 Refer to (a passage, book, or author) as evidence
>   for or justification of an argument or statement, especially in a
>   scholarly work:
>
> ...
>
> Derivatives
>
> citable
>
> *The nice thing about written information, is that it's **citable.***

*[Referential](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/referential)* combines the other two in a general sense of reference:

> adjective
>
> 1. Containing or of the nature of references or allusions.
>
> Derivatives
>
> referentiality
>
> *The nice thing about written information, is that it's **referential.***
>   *The nice thing about written information, is it's **referentiality.***

Answer (score 2):

Please see this link

[[Merriam-Webster Dictionary ]](http://nws.merriam-webster.com/opendictionary/newword_display_alpha.php?letter=Re&last=80)

While it may be classed as a "New" word or even slang, it is definitely an acceptable word to use in modern English.  The sentence used above if perfectly serviceable.

Comment: One gets the feeling that it would be more towards the 'acceptable in formal registers' end of the cline than say 'refreshify'. But 'refrigeradar' takes the biscuit.

Comment: Do biscuits need refrigeradion?